# UIViewController, Auto Layout and iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, iphone-6

We are updating our Auto Layout-using app to natively support iPhone 6 resolution. We added the iPhone 6 launch image, and most of the views scaled nicely.

However, we are experiencing a small annoyance: when loading new view controllers, the views have the iPhone 5 resolution on the `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method. The view only gets the iPhone 6 resolution when you hit `viewWillAppear`.

Why is this? Is there anything we can configure or modify to make the views have the final resolution on `viewDidLoad` already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right place to get geometry data from your views is in the method:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews;
```

This is called when auto layout finishes laying the views. Please beware this method can be called multiple times, i.e. after a rotation of the device.

**EDIT**

In interface builder, there is an option to set the size for the simulated metrics. I'm not sure if this has to do only with what interface builder displays, or also with the frame of the view at load time. Maybe you can change it and give it a try.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This answer looks sensible. Thanks! I still wonder why all views think they have a width of 320 points during `viewDidLoad`... Would it be an artifact on the UIKit framework itself or would it be because our project was started before the iPhone 6 was released? Anyway, if a better answer doesn't pop up I'll accept this.

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez are you using xib's/nib's?

Comment: Yeah, quite a few of them.

Comment: Explicitly setting the size to iPhone 6 on the .xibs makes it to return the iPhone 6 on `viewDidLoad`, both on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. Setting it to *inferred* makes it behave like I stated in the answer (it returns the iPhone 5 resolution both on iPhone 6 and on iPhone 4S. It'd be great if the *inferred* option would already return the correct device resolution on `viewDidLoad`.